# How to compute color contrast ratio between two UIColor instances

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I'm looking for a concise way to compute the color contrast ratio between two `UIColor` instances in Swift. I've found examples that are close but are overly complicated or outdated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## `UIColor` extension with contrast ratio and luminance

The following `UIColor` extension includes a static and instance contrast ratio method. A bonus luminance method is included since it is used by the static `contrastRatio(between:and:)` method.

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor {

    static func contrastRatio(between color1: UIColor, and color2: UIColor) -> CGFloat {
        // https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G18.html#G18-tests

        let luminance1 = color1.luminance()
        let luminance2 = color2.luminance()

        let luminanceDarker = min(luminance1, luminance2)
        let luminanceLighter = max(luminance1, luminance2)

        return (luminanceLighter + 0.05) / (luminanceDarker + 0.05)
    }

    func contrastRatio(with color: UIColor) -> CGFloat {
        return UIColor.contrastRatio(between: self, and: color)
    }

    func luminance() -> CGFloat {
        // https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G18.html#G18-tests

        let ciColor = CIColor(color: self)

        func adjust(colorComponent: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
            return (colorComponent < 0.04045) ? (colorComponent / 12.92) : pow((colorComponent + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4)
        }

        return 0.2126 * adjust(colorComponent: ciColor.red) + 0.7152 * adjust(colorComponent: ciColor.green) + 0.0722 * adjust(colorComponent: ciColor.blue)
    }
}
```

### Example Use

```
// static method
let contrastRatio1 = UIColor.contrastRatio(between: UIColor.black, and: UIColor.white)
print(contrastRatio1) // 21.0

// instance method
let contrastRatio2 = UIColor.black.contrastRatio(with: UIColor.white)
print(contrastRatio2) // 21.0
```

---

#### Note

Following these links:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#predefined
- https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core/issues/1629#issuecomment-509880306

For predefinite colorspace (like in iOS see this https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/712/) and also in general the correct THRESHOLD value is **0.04045** and not 0.03928 ([read more](https://entropymine.com/imageworsener/srgbformula/))

Comment: See more about [relative luminance](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Relative_luminance)

Answer (score 1):

If building for `WatchOS` where `CoreImage` is not available or for whatever reason you do not want to rely on `CoreImage` and therefore `CIColor` is unavailable, replace @Mobile Dan's `luminance` function with:

```
  private func luminance() -> CGFloat {
  // https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G18.html#G18-tests

    func adjust(colorComponent: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
      return (colorComponent < 0.04045) ? (colorComponent / 12.92) : pow((colorComponent + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4)
    }

    var red: CGFloat = 0
    var green: CGFloat = 0
    var blue: CGFloat = 0
    var alpha: CGFloat = 0
    getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

    return 0.2126 * adjust(colorComponent: red)
      + 0.7152 * adjust(colorComponent: green)
      + 0.0722 * adjust(colorComponent: blue)
  }
```

Comment: 0.03928 should become 0.04045 since you are using 12.92 instead of 12.92321 if you want to handle the rounding error

Answer (score 1):

The SwiftUI way of doing the same:

```swift
import SwiftUI

extension Color {
    var components: (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, opacity: CGFloat) {
        var r: CGFloat = 0
        var g: CGFloat = 0
        var b: CGFloat = 0
        var o: CGFloat = 0
        guard UIColor(self).getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &o) else {
            print("Could not fetch color components for \(self)")
            return (0, 0, 0, 0)
        }

        return (r, g, b, o)
    }

    func contrastRatio(against color: Color) -> Double {
        let luminance1 = self.luminance()
        let luminance2 = color.luminance()

        let luminanceDarker = min(luminance1, luminance2)
        let luminanceLighter = max(luminance1, luminance2)

        return (luminanceLighter + 0.05) / (luminanceDarker + 0.05)
    }

    func luminance() -> Double {
        func adjust(colorComponent: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
            return (colorComponent < 0.04045) ? (colorComponent / 12.92) : pow((colorComponent + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4)
        }

        return 0.2126 * adjust(colorComponent: self.components.red) + 0.7152 * adjust(colorComponent: self.components.green) + 0.0722 * adjust(colorComponent: self.components.blue)
    }
}
```